# Doubts related to developing android app

Tags: android

In my android app,I want to get a video played in one activity and show its relevant questions in another activity.The questions should be displayed one by one ie. next question should appear only on clicking next.How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Launch Second Activity using Intents.
[Intents](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent)
You can also use Fragments for your purpose [Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

well it depends , the most appropriate  is startActivityForResult or startActivity simply. On the click of the item, gather all relevant information then stored in a intent from which you then start the activity. Please serialize your data using gson. Or using peaceable interface.

A bit more info.
When we want to pass objects between two components in Android, these objects have to implements Android Parcelable interface.Parcelable Android is a serialization and deserialization mechanism.

Comment: gson link http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/